# Message body text + label.text

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to create a message that has a string text and also reference a label's text too.

I have this, but I'm not sure how to tie it together.

```
NSString *message = @"Lets meet here:"; _addressLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lets meet here: %@", _addressLabel.text];
```

The `%@` tells the method where to substitute the argument - you can even have multiple:

```
NSString *foo = @"foo";
NSString *bar = @"bar";
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", foo, bar];
```

will make `message` be `foo : bar`.